# Не хочет находится Минимальное значение все время 0. (min)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int **ptrarray, N;
int min = 0;

int Function_Min_elem( int min, int N, int **ptrarray)
{
    for (int count_row = 0; count_row < N + 15; count_row++)
    {
        for (int count_column = 0; count_column < N + 15; count_column++)
        {
            if (min > ptrarray[count_row][count_column])
                min = ptrarray[count_row][count_column];
        }

    // Нахождение мниимального элемента;
    }

    return min; 
}


void Function_sum_elem1(int N,  int sum)
{
    for (int count_row = 0; count_row < N + 15; count_row++)
    {
        for (int count_column = 0; count_column < N + 15; count_column++)
            sum = ptrarray[count_row][count_column] + sum;
            //Сумма элементов массива
    }

    cout << "  " << endl;
    cout << " Сумма элементов массива = " << sum << endl;
}

int Create_Massiv(int **ptrarray,  int N )
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < N + 15; counter++)
       ptrarray[counter] = new int[N + 15];
       //создаем массив

    for (int count_row = 0; count_row < N + 15; count_row++)
    {
        for (int count_column = 0; count_column < N + 15; count_column++)
        {
            ptrarray[count_row][count_column] = rand() % ((15 + N) * 2 + 1) - 15 - N;
            // Заполняем массив
        }

    }

    return **ptrarray;
}

void Print(int **ptrarray, int N)
{
    cout << setw(5);
    for (int count_row = 0; count_row < N + 15; count_row++)
    {
        for (int count_column = 0; count_column < N + 15; count_column++)
            cout << ptrarray[count_row][count_column] << setw(5);
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Вывод елементов массива
    cout << endl;
}


int Vvod()
{
    cout << "Введите  натруальное число  N" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    return N;
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    system("mode con cols=200 lines=200");

    int sum = 0,  sum_el_mat = 0, sum_el_mat2 = 0;

    Vvod();

    if (N >-12)
        // Ограничение 
    {
        cout << "" << endl;

        ptrarray = new int*[N + 15];
        ///
        Create_Massiv(ptrarray,N);

        Print(ptrarray, N);


        Function_sum_elem1(N,sum);

        Function_Min_elem(min, N, ptrarray);

        cout << " Наименьший елемент = " << min << endl;

        int Mmin = abs(min);
        cout << " Наименьший елемент gj vjl = " << Mmin << endl;

        // Абсолютное значение min элемента
```

Comment: Что это? Оно даже после приведения в человеческий вид не собирается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для чего в функции `Function_Min_elem( int min, int N, int **ptrarray)` `min` во входящих параметрах ?

1. В `Function_Min_elem` работа идет с локальной переменной `min`, а при вызове `Function_Min_elem` присваивания глобальной переменной `min` нигде нет.
2. Еще при вызове `Function_Min_elem(min, N, ptrarray)` приходит 0, а в массиве все элементы могут быть > 0, и вы получаете 0 как минимальный.

**Вариант 1.** Вызывать `Function_Min_elem` с первым элементом массива и присваивать результат глобальной `min`

```
int main()
{
    ...

    if (N >-12)
    {
        ...

        min = ptrarray[0][0]; //инициализируем min
        min = Function_Min_elem(min, N, ptrarray); //записываем результат в min

        ...
    }
}
```

**Вариант 2.**. Внутри функции присваивать элементу min значение первого элемента массива. В данном случае лучше вообще убрать из параметров min аргумент, он там будет лишним. И не забыть так-же записать результат в глобальную переменную `min = Function_Min_elem(min, N, ptrarray);`

```
int Function_Min_elem( int min, int N, int **ptrarray)
{
    min = ptrarray[0][0]; 
       //Как вариант здесь min элементу присваивать первый элемент массива

    for (int count_row = 0; count_row < N + 15; count_row++)
    {
        for (int count_column = 0; count_column < N + 15; count_column++)
        {
            if (min > ptrarray[count_row][count_column])
                min = ptrarray[count_row][count_column];
        }
    }

    return min; 
}
```